# Why standard errors in macro-level variables are normally higher than that in firm-level variables?

Tags: finance, standard-deviation

From [this dicussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/529777/319998), the commentor said

> Lastly, firm fixed effects may absorb more variation and likely
> reduced the size of their standard errors.

In practice, I also mainly see that the standard error for country-level mainly higher than that of firm-level variables. I am wondering if there is any mathematical or intuitive way to explain this phenomenon.

Comment: Consider a study of 10,000 firms over 2 countries. It should be intuitively, for such a dataset, why it's easier to estimate a slope parameter for a firm-level variable then a country-level variable.

Comment: @Jase Thank you for your convern, could you please explain it more, thank you so much, if  it can be clarified in an answer, would be much appreciated.

Comment: In general one has more samples by say, a few orders of magnitude, so the larger sample size will reduce the standard error, even if we account for possible correlations across samplees.